# oracle joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, one which look something like this

```
Position(posNum, posTitle, posSalary)
```

sample data:

```
insert into position values ('P0009','Systems Engineers',5600);
insert into position values ('P0010','Senior Lecturer', 9000);
insert into position values ('P0011','Database Administrator',4500);
```

and another table like this

```
SKILL(skill,skillDesc)
```

sample data:

```
insert into skill values ('SK009','Database Optimization');
insert into skill values ('SK010','Oracle XE 11g');
```

which are referenced by a table like this

```
SKILLNEEDED(skillneededPosNum, skillneededSkill)
```

sample data:

```
insert into skillneeded values ('P0009','SK010',10);
insert into skillneeded values ('P0010','SK401',10);
insert into skillneeded values ('P0010','SK807',10);
```

is there any mistake in my query as it returns no rows found which should not be the case

```
SELECT p.posNum, p.posTitle, p.posOfferedBy
  FROM POSITION p
  JOIN SKILLNEEDED c
    ON p.posNum = c.skillneededPosNum
  JOIN SKILL s
    ON s.skill = c.skillneededSkill
 WHERE s.skillDesc = 'Oracle XE 11g' AND s.skillDesc = 'Database Design';
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435694/Understanding-Table-Joins-using-SQL first of all understand the concepts of joining from this link... and try to do it again...

Comment: it would be helpful if you added some sample data

Comment: @Rohan i've added some data, so I've read some resources online and they suggest to use full outer join is it true?

Comment: I was checking the data. Your last clause mentions skill 'Oracle XE 11g' & 'Database Design', but there is no record that has both these skill code assigned to them. Only P0009-Systems Engineer has skill SK010-Oracle XE 11g, but not both skills

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there should be an `OR` instead of an `AND` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query fails because the entire WHERE is applied to each row.  Clearly it cannot be true that `a=1 AND a=2` so your query returns zero rows.

This solution is not necessarily the most elegant but I think it illustrates the principle.  It uses the WITH clause to make a sub-query which can be referenced multiple times in the main query.

```
with skillz as
   ( select p.posNum, s.skillDesc
     from SKILLNEEDED c
          join SKILL s
              ON s.skill = c.skillneededSkill
          join POSITION p
              ON p.posNum = c.skillneededPosNum )
select p.*
from POSITION p
     join skillz s1 
          on s1.posNum = p.posNum 
     join skillz s2 
          on s2.posNum = p.posNum 
WHERE s1.skillDesc = 'Oracle XE 11g' 
AND s2.skillDesc = 'Database Design';
```